# Has anyone managed to filter logs in the macos `log stream` command using pid?

Tags: macos, logging, pid, xcode-command-line-tools

I've been wrecking my brain trying to get the `log stream` command on macos to work with a passed in pid.

I have an app `FooBar` with a pid `12345`.

The command:

```
log stream --debug --info --process FooBar
```

Works perfectly fine. On using `ps auf | grep "FooBar"` or the `Activity Monitor` to get the app's pid, and then doing the below command:

```
log stream --debug --info --process 12345
```

I never get any logs. Can anyone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong? I can't find any example of anyone actually using the pid online.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's `log` facility allows selecting the relevant messages with its "predicate-based filtering". It enables quite elaborate filtering via:

```
log stream --predicate 'PREDICATE BASED FILTER'
```

The `PREDICATE BASED FILTER` is an expression in the predicate DSL, which is outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html). Fields specific to the `log` facility are available via

```
log help predicates
```

Predicate-based filtering is quite powerful, but unfortunately it can get verbose. It seems that Apple wanted to "elevate" some of the common predicates into the top-level flags.

```
log --process ProcessName
```

is an example of such "elevated" predicate. Its full form is

```
log --predicate 'process == "ProcessName"'
```

Unfortunately, there's no "elevated" predicate for filtering via `pid`, but it's supported via the full predicate syntax:

```
log --predicate 'processID == 12345'
```